# how to compare strings in vector in c++?

Tags: c++

hey I have class containing

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;
struct student
{
    std::string ID;
    std::string Name;
    std::vector<std::string> friends;

};
```

And main function contains

```
int main() {

    vector<student> List_Students = { { "d123", "Jacob", {"e321"} }, { "e321", "Abo", {"d123", "e456"} }, { "e456","Mark",{} } };

    for (auto& s : List_Students)
    {
        cout << s.ID << "\t" << s.Name;

        for (auto& f : s.friends)
        {
            cout << " " <<  f << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    
}
```

this yields output as expected
output:

```
d123    Jacob e321
e321    Abo d123  e456
e456    Mark
```

my question is how can I compare the vector of friends with IDs so that so that after it shows friends it shows their names with it. Expected output:

```
d123    Jacob e321 (Abo)
e321    Abo d123 (Jacob)  e456 (Mark)
e456    Mark (No friends)
```

quite new to c++ any help would be appreciated thank you

Comment: Store friends in a `std::map` instead of a `std::vector`?

Comment: I think you should use a map<std::string, std::pair<string,vector> > , now you can find values corresponding to keys and then first element will be your name. Student_list['key'].first , so no need to use struct at all

Comment: @saumitramallick that will "work", but it will be less intuitive for other readers, or even the author in the future, to know that `first` means Name and `second` means Friends. Don't obscure code when you don't need to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the standard [`std::find_if()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) algorithm, eg

```cpp
...
#include <algorithm>
...

int main() {

    vector<student> List_Students = {
        { "d123", "Jacob", {"e321"} },
        { "e321", "Abo", {"d123", "e456"} },
        { "e456", "Mark", {} }
    };

    for (auto& s : List_Students)
    {
        cout << s.ID << "\t" << s.Name;

        if (s.friends.empty())
        {
            cout << " (No friends)";
        }
        else
        {
            for (auto& f : s.friends)
            {
                cout << " " << f << " ";

                auto iter = find_if(List_Students.begin(), List_Students.end(),
                    [&](const student &s2){ return s2.ID == f; }
                );

                if (iter != List_Students.end())
                {
                    cout << "(" << iter->Name << ") ";
                }
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Or, like @Ch3steR said in comments, you can store the names in a `std::map`:

```cpp
...
#include <map>
#include <utility>
...

int main() {

    vector<student> List_Students = {
        { "d123", "Jacob", {"e321"} },
        { "e321", "Abo", {"d123", "e456"} },
        { "e456", "Mark", {} }
    };
    map<string, string> names;

    for (auto& s : List_Students)
    {
        names.insert(make_pair(s.ID, s.Name));
    }

    for (auto& s : List_Students)
    {
        cout << s.ID << "\t" << s.Name;

        if (s.friends.empty())
        {
            cout << " (No friends)";
        }
        else
        {
            for (auto& f : s.friends)
            {
                cout << " " << f << " (" << names[f] << ") ";
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Alternatively:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

struct student
{
    string Name;
    vector<string> friends;
};

int main() {

    map<string, student> List_Students = {
        { "d123", { "Jacob", {"e321"} } },
        { "e321", { "Abo", {"d123", "e456"} } },
        { "e456", { "Mark", {} } }
    };

    for (auto& elem : List_Students)
    {
        auto &s = elem.second;

        cout << elem.first << "\t" << s.Name;

        if (s.friends.empty())
        {
            cout << " (No friends)";
        }
        else
        {
            for (auto& f : s.friends)
            {
                cout << " " << f << " (" << List_Students[f].Name << ") ";
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we make `map` as a static member and get friends' names through a convenience function. Something like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/3383hM5jd) or is it a bad design choice?